# Google Maps API: Requesting any place labels given longitude and latitude?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on an iPhone map application and wanted to know whether it was possible to request any labels visible on Google Maps given a longitude/latitude and radius?

For example if I gave the following location to [this Google Maps API](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=stanford+university&aq=&sll=37.876276,-122.24556&sspn=0.027303,0.051756&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Stanford+University,+Menlo+Park,+Santa+Clara,+California&ll=37.428132,-122.173231&spn=0.00184,0.003235&z=18), I would get back McCullough Hall, Moore Hall, etc. The list would be any place labels visible on  the map (doesn't have to be just restaurants, businesses).

If this is possible can you direct me to where I can learn more about this. If this isn't possible, can you direct me towards another API where it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Googles reverse geocoding](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding), I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, you cannot!.
The only way is to search for places by name and get a reference key to query the place details including lat/lng. Not the other way around.

IMHO, this is mainly a policy of Google instead of being technical limitation.