# Is there a way to get a place name based on coordinates?

Tags: c#, geolocation, coordinates, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

Given the coordinates of a location, is there a way to get the place name?

I don't mean the address, I mean the "title" of the place, e.g.:

```
Coordinates: 76.07, -62.0 // or whatever they are
Address: 157 Riverside Avenue, Champaign, Illinois
Place name: REO Speedwagon's Rehearsal Spot
```

-or:

```
Coordinates: 76.07, -62.0 // or whatever they are
Address: 77 Sunset Strip, Hollywood, CA
Place name: Famous Amos Cookies
```

So is there a reverse geocoding web service or something that I can call, a la:

```
string placeName = GetPlaceNameForCoordinates(76.07, -62.0)
```

...that will return "Wal*Mart" or "Columbia Jr. College" or whatever is appropriate?

I've found references to other languages, such as java and ios (Objective C, I guess), but nothing specifically for how to do it in C# from a Windows store app...

### UPDATE

I already have this for getting the address (adapted from Freeman's "Metro Revealed: Building Windows 8 apps with XAML and C#" page 75):

```
public static async Task<string> GetStreetAddressForCoordinates(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org");
    HttpResponseMessage httpResult = await httpClient.GetAsync(
        String.Format("reverse?format=json&lat={0}&lon={1}", latitude, longitude));

    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(await httpResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

    return string.format("{0} {1}", jsonObject.GetNamedObject("address").GetNamedString("house"),
                                    jsonObject.GetNamedObject("address").GetNamedString("road"));
 }
```

...but I see nothing for Place Name in their docs; they seem to supply house, road, village, town, city, county, postcode, and country, but no Place Name.

Comment: This question asks a similar thing, hopefully gives you some more idea's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043077/get-place-details-or-building-names-using-latitude-and-longitude-in-google-maps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually store the latitude/longitude coordinates and then use GMaps to look up the location, then "on a best effort basis" - look up the place's name using the address - again via Google Maps.

```
static string baseUri = 
  "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=false";
string location = string.Empty;

public static void RetrieveFormatedAddress(string lat, string lng)
{
    string requestUri = string.Format(baseUri, lat, lng);

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        string result = wc.DownloadString(requestUri);
        var xmlElm = XElement.Parse(result);
        var status = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants() where 
            elm.Name == "status" select elm).FirstOrDefault();
        if (status.Value.ToLower() == "ok")
        {
            var res = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants() where 
                elm.Name == "formatted_address" select elm).FirstOrDefault();
            requestUri = res.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Here's a simple version of the reverse:

```
public static Coordinate GetCoordinates(string region)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {

        string uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q='" + region + 
          "'&output=csv&key=sadfwet56346tyeryhretu6434tertertreyeryeryE1";

        string[] geocodeInfo = client.DownloadString(uri).Split(',');

        return new Coordinate(Convert.ToDouble(geocodeInfo[2]), 
                   Convert.ToDouble(geocodeInfo[3]));
    }
}

public struct Coordinate
{
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    public Coordinate(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        lat = latitude;
        lng = longitude;

    }

    public double Latitude { get { return lat; } set { lat = value; } }
    public double Longitude { get { return lng; } set { lng = value; } }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't a method named RetrieveFormattedAddress() return a string?

Comment: This is now outdated. You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=32.12,34.12&sensor=false

Answer (score 3):

> I've found references to other languages, such as java and ios (Objective C, I guess)

Look closely into those references - most of them are likely to use *reverse geocoding* web services... and those could be used by your Windows Store app as well. Pick a service which has appropriate features and restrictions for your app, and make HTTP requests to it. (You may even find there's an appropriate client library available, although I guess that's relatively unlikely right now, due to the recent-ness of Windows 8...)

Comment: I don't see a place name in map quest, either. I'd prefer if Bing had it; next choice openstreetmap, which I'm already using as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>           Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator(); 
>            Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
>             string lat = geoposition.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude.ToString();
>             string lon = geoposition.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude.ToString();
>             string baseUri = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=false", lat, lon);
>             HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
>             var response = await client.GetStringAsync(baseUri);
>             var responseElement = XElement.Parse(response);
>             IEnumerable<XElement>statusElement = from st in responseElement.Elements("status") select st;
>             if (statusElement.FirstOrDefault() != null)
>             {
>                 string status = statusElement.FirstOrDefault().Value;
>                 if (status.ToLower() == "ok")
>                 {
>                     IEnumerable<XElement> resultElement = from rs in responseElement.Elements("result") select rs;
>                     if (resultElement.FirstOrDefault() != null)
>                     {
>                         IEnumerable<XElement> addressElement = from ad in resultElement.FirstOrDefault().Elements("address_component") select ad;
>                         foreach (XElement element in addressElement)
>                         {
>                             IEnumerable<XElement> typeElement = from te in element.Elements("type") select te;
>                             string type = typeElement.FirstOrDefault().Value;
>                             if(type=="locality")
>                             {
>                                 IEnumerable<XElement> cityElement = from ln in element.Elements("long_name") select ln;
>                                 string city = cityElement.FirstOrDefault().Value;
>                                 break;
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Comment: I have used Google Maps to look up the current location's latitude, longitude and city info.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code in c# console application. Pass the path of your CSV that has coordinate and it will fetch the address tag from the response and place it in a CSV

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Google_Padouri

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Google obj = new Google();
            obj.Execute();
        }



}

class Google
{

    public void Execute()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter complete csv path");
            string path = Console.ReadLine();

            //string path = @"C:\tmp\google\test_file.csv";

            string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int count = 0;

            foreach(string row in rows)
            {
                string[] arr = row.Split(',');
                string lat = arr[0];
                string lng = arr[1];

                if (count > 0) 
                {
                    result = GetResult(lat, lng);
                    if (result.Length > 1)
                    {
                        result = GetAddress(result);
                        if (result.Length > 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Working on row number " + count);
                            sb.Append(lat + "," + lng + "," + result.Replace(",", "") + "\n");

                            //if(count==200)
                            //{
                            //    break;
                            //}
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Could not fetch results");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Google API response failed");
                    }
                }
                count = count+1;
            }

            string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
            file = file + "_output.csv";
            string fullpath = dir + "\\" + file;
            using (StreamWriter wrtier = File.CreateText(fullpath))
            {
                wrtier.Write(sb.ToString());
            }
            Console.Write("File compiled successfully");
            Console.Read();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
        }
    }

    public string GetResult(string lat,string lang)
    {

        string method = "GET";
        string URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";
        string Key = "key=YOUR_KEY";
        string Sensor = "sensor=false&";
        string latlng = "latlng=" + lat + "," + lang;
        string result = string.Empty;

        URL = URL + Key + Sensor + latlng;

        try
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");

                switch (method.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "GET":
                        result = wc.DownloadString(URL);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
            Console.Read();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public string GetAddress(string data)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (data.Length > 1)
            {
                JToken token = JToken.Parse(data);
                JArray array = JArray.Parse(token["results"].ToString());



                    result = array.First["formatted_address"].ToString();


            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Console.Read();
        }
        return result;
    }


   }

}
```